# Do Functions with dynamic (inline) SQL perform better than dynamic (inline) SQL in PostgreSQL?

Tags: .net, database, postgresql

I'm pretty new to PostgreSQL and have a basic design question I'd like some advice on.

Our company has 1000+ identical schemas defined in our PostgreSQL DB.
We have separate Schemas (work places) defined for each of our clients.
The overall DB Schema design is something which cannot be altered.

We have to create routines which will gather data from all the schemas and store it in DataTables in a separate (centralized) schema.

One approach would be to write a .Net based app using he npgsql interface. The application would iterate over all the schemas and run dynamic (inline) SQL to return the desired data.

Another approach would be to push all the data gathering routines into PostgreSQL functions. The functions would contain dynamic SQL, accept a schema as parameter, and then run that SQL against the target schema.

Is there any difference in the performance of the two approaches?
I'm trying to figure out which approach will be best in terms of performance and maintainability.

Is there a better approach to take?

Thanks,
JohnB

Answer (score 0):

You just need to navigate between schemas using a single function defined elsewhere:

```
create table public.t (i int);
```

Create a function in a certain schema that uses an object that is common to all schemas:

```
create function public.f()
returns t as $$
    select * from t;
$$ language sql;
```

Navigate to the schema where you want to use that function:

```
create schema s1;
set schema 's1';
create table s1.t (like public.t);
insert into s1.t (i) values (1);
```

Since 's1' is the current schema the function will query the object in that schema:

```
select * from public.f();
 i 
---
 1
```

Search for options in manipulating the schema search_path